# filepicker.io evernote

Tags: javascript, filepicker.io

I'm using the filepicker.io to grab an evernote note - the problem is that it dosent seem to handle if an evernote note contains more than one object.

For example one note might contain text, image and audio. Is this a genuine limitation or have I overlooked something?

Comment: Hi Matt. I'm a filepicker and wanted to reach out. Evernote is a tricky beast as it is both a file (in that it is content) and a folder (in that it contains files). Therefore, we do our best to figure out what to return based on the mimetype that you provide us and the objects in the file. Sometimes we don't do such a great job and sometimes, the right answer on what to return isn't clear to us as humans and thus impossible to write the code. Feel free to reach out to me directly (liyan@filepicker.io) and we can take a look at your individual case.

Comment: You should probably discuss a solution in public so that your other customers currently trying to integrate to evernote through filepicker could benefit as well.